# Customize the send email page in cases

Tags: case, send-email

we need to somehow be able to send copy of the email sent from cases "send email" relatedlist to a particular email address. From whatever i have looked at i am unable to find a way to cc to particular email address automatically. The end users always forget to add the email address in the cc.

One way i can think is to completely recode this send email page in VF.  But this seems too much work to get the cc populated.

Is there any other way like a trigger or something? Not sure which object i would need to write the trigger and if the trigger would fire after the email is sent.

Any pointers would be of help

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i prefill the cc field in send email page of cases](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58169/how-do-i-prefill-the-cc-field-in-send-email-page-of-cases)

Comment: this indeed seems a duplicate of your earlier question. If you feel like restating your question it would be better to edit the original one or create a new one (as you did) and close the original one. Otherwise the questions risks being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I initially started of this question on how to get the whole page of send email as VF page, the more thought i put into it, it just was looking too much for adding a cc to the email. I would rather close the previous one than this as this has a decent answer to it . I have deleted the previous question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** customize the standard Emails related list under Case.

Alternatively,

You can achieve this through following steps-from Activity related list:

1) Please copy the **javascript code of "Send Email" button's onclick event**. You can get this through Firebug/any browser's console. This has a link to the Standard Send Email page with few parameters like Case id.

```
navigateToUrl('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=5004000000Hl36D&retURL=%2F5004000000Hl36D',null,'newEmail');
```

2) Create a new Button on  **Activity** and name it as "**Send Email**" and in the button's **javascript** section,
add the above code and replace the Case id with your case id through merge fields.

3) After replacing, to the first parameter (i.e) the URL of send email page, add another parameter "**p4=CC_Email_Address**" .
(i.e) the code will be like the below statement

```
navigateToUrl('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=CASE_ID&retURL=%2FCASE_ID&p4=CC_EMAIL',null,'newEmail');
```

4) Add this button to the Activity related list of the Case layout.

5)Now when you click on the Send Email button in Activity Related List, You'll have the **CC_EMAIL** as well in the **CC** field.

Comment: Nice answer! Alternatively, here's the Idea link to include this into standard SF functionality: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000J2QXAA0

Comment: @Vignex . thats a nice way to do, just have one question though, how do i create a button on activity? I cant seem to find an option to create one under Customize ->Activities->Activity buttons

Comment: @Prady Please use Customize ->Activities-> Task Buttons, Links, and Actions

Comment: @Vignex,@Prady :Hello ,im having the similar issue.We are using the standard functionality page Task Send an email page.The issue is the cc'd email ids are getting copied .In the controller we are passing the string url as '' String redUrl = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid='+cas.contactId+'&p26='+cas.Email_to_Case_Address__c +'&rtype=003&p3_lkid=' +cas.id +
                         '&p4='+cas.Email_CC_Address__c+'&p5=' + cas.Email_BCC_Address__c + '&p6='+subject+     
                        '&retURL=/'+ cas.id ;'' .Any suggestion highly appreciated.